# How to get image from WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, session, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control, after navigating a page I need to download the image.
I used the following code:

```
HtmlElementCollection tagsColl = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img");
foreach (HtmlElement currentTag in tagsColl)
{
     ...
     using (var client = new WebClient())
     {
           ...
           client.DownloadFile(currentTag.GetAttribute("src"), path);
           ...
     }
}
```

but, in this case webclient starts a new session, and link in new session is not correct.
I need to do this in same session as webbrowser, only in this case i get a correct link to the image.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try downloading the image using [URLDownloadToFile](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon/URLDownloadToFile%20.html), which should give you the same session and cache as used by `WebBrowser`.